# Can you say that since one time pad encryption is unbreakable, it is the best if used properly?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad

I'm currently reading about one time pad encryption, and I have a question. They say OTP encryption is unbreakable, and this can be proved mathematically. This is provided that the key used is truly random and is used only one time, right? What if I come with a whole system (can be software or hardware or a combination of both) to force these two conditions? Will I have the best & ideal encryption solution?

Say for example the two sides willing to exchange information are getting the keys by connecting to a server that is online all the time. The server will ensure the keys generated are random, and will ensure that a key is never used again. The users at each side will only have to have an internet connection and a mechanism to exchange information. The information will travel via the internet encrypted using the one time pad key generated randomly by the server.

Am I making any sense here? I just started reading about one time pad, and started wondering about this. There are many websites that will tell you that one time pad isn't practical at all, because you can't really come up with a truly random number or something like this.

Addition:

Do these guys offer anything special in key distribution? They say they have perfected implementing OTP over time.

http://www.mils.com/en/technology/unbreakable-encryption/#1

Comment: If used properly, the best security system is telling the other party whatever you have to say to them, in person, with no one else around in a room you've personally swept for recording devices. The reason we don't do that is that we *have* to worry about practicality - a OTP only works in very specific circumstances, which alone makes it suboptimal.

Comment: "Say for example the two sides willing to exchange information are getting the keys by connecting to a server that is online all the time." Woah, hold on a second there. How exactly are you securing that connection? With a different one time pad? How did the clients obtain _that_ pad? See the problem?

Comment: 'Best' is subjective.  It all depends on one's requirements.  Speed of encryption, tools available, resistance to cracking, ease of key exchange... the list goes on.

Comment: Remember what the fundamental principle of cryptography is: *you can leverage the secrecy of a key into the security of a message against certain attacks*. Newcomers to crypto often fall in love with the mathematics and gloss over the significant difficulties in that "the secrecy of the key" part.

Comment: @cpast someone's been watching the Sopranos, I see?

Comment: You can't currently exchange a OTP over the internet and still have the security of a OTP. The security would be limited to whatever method you used to exchange the key.  This isn't to say a OTP is useless: in certain applications it is the best choice. I believe so-called 'numbers stations' still broadcast messages using a OTP to encrypt the message. If an OTP is used then it is usually exchanged by hand, and it the responsibility of each party to keep it secure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is using a pseudo-random key considered more practical than a one-time pad?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12733/why-is-using-a-pseudo-random-key-considered-more-practical-than-a-one-time-pad)

Comment: In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they're not. One time pads are unbreakable, but there's very serious practical considerations when it comes to actually using them.

Comment: @corsiKa Actually, such precautions are not that uncommon. There's a decent industry around making equipment to sweep rooms for bugs. Such sweeps are done commonly in corporate, government, and VIP protection situations.

Answer (score 84):

**Key distribution is the problem.**

In your scenario, you use a server to communicate the one-time pads to the users.  But how is *that* communication protected?  Not by a one-time pad, or it wouldn't be necessary.  Let's say it's SSL with AES 128.  Then, wham, your cryptosystem is as secure as SSL with AES 128 - pretty secure, but not as secure as a one-time pad.

The mils guys you reference appear to be offering physical devices which you load a one-time keystream onto (and can use it from).  Again, key distribution is a problem.  You could buy two hard drives, load terabytes of keystream on them, and send one to your buddy... how?  Do you trust USPS?  Fedex?  Courier?  Diplomatic pouch?  All of these can be compromised.  The only perfectly encrypted way to send them would be to encrypt them with a one-time pa... crap, it happened again.

Comment: There is always the Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: @SpencerDoak But then you are only as secure as the Key used for the exchange - and then you wouldn't need the server at all and can exchange keys directly... And then you start worrying about authentication and MITM...

Comment: There is a (still fairly theoretical) answer to this problem: entangled photons. Quantum Crypto doesn't allow us to directly encrypt a message, but it does allow us to (slowly) distribute a key. OTP is the obvious encryption method to be used with such keys.

Comment: @MSalters And there are already effective attacks (plural, two that I know of off the top of my head) against quantum entanglement (or at the very least, existing crypto systems using quantum entanglement).  So that's not a solution either.

Comment: No the problem is Key **Management**, as the key materiel could be compromised or lost, or an attacker could 'de-synchronise' the 2 parties (DOS).

Comment: There is an infinite supply of one-time pads on YouTube.

Comment: @HotLicks, a one-time pad must also be sufficiently random.  While YouTube is random in many senses, mathematically it's not sufficiently random data.

Comment: @gowenfawr - One simply needs to know that you count the words in the lead soccer (football) article on the BBC sports site, use that as an index into an article on CNN to get the ID of the specific YouTube video and the offset into it for starting. And, of course, run the data through a reasonably good hash algorithm before using it as a pad.

Comment: @gowenfawr I'm not sure if this is true; but I've thought for ages that it would be simple and secure to exchange physical keys once, then use those keys to exchange further keys.

Comment: @SeanPedersen The problem with using that for a OTP is that you need to use one bit of OTP key material for each bit you encrypt. So if you want to encrypt 1024 bits of your next OTP, you have to use 1024 bits of your current one, so there's really no point in doing so.

Comment: @gowenfawr I think you're overstating the key distribution problem. There absolutely *are* situations where you have a better ability to keep physical media secure than an electronic communication; if you give your spy a pack of OTPs in person, or if you fly a tape accompanied at all times by trusted courier (that's not an unusual way to carry small diplomatic pouches, and the courier can report if the pouch was opened so you can throw out that pad), you can find yourself in a situation where you trust your key distribution as much as you trust the other side to not share the message.

Comment: Basically, to paraphrase a few answers on another question, the basic function of an OTP is to shift the problem of "keep this thing secure" to a time when it's easier -- secure communication of the pad can happen on your schedule instead of when you need to send the real message, because as long as the key stays secure the message stays secure.

Comment: @cpast, you're correct, physical key distribution is certainly possible, and I suspect governments do it all the time. But it's impractical for most users, and antithetical to the OP's stated goal, which was to enable OTP use via online key distribution.

Comment: The point is that OTP is only as secure as the key distribution channel. Therefore OTP can only EVER be implemented using out of bound key exchange. Attempts to transfer the key in channel results in the channel itself as being the weakest link.

Answer (score 31):

No, because you misunderstand the meaning of "best" in a security context.  Contrary to popular opinion, "most secure" and "best" are not synonyms, rather, security is entirely about balancing usability and security.  It is about risk management.

The most secure drive on the planet is writing to DevNull (the bit bucket) on the bottom of the ocean in a locked box in a pile of concrete, in a faraday cage, sunk in lava with no cables or wires to it.  Absolutely nobody will ever get any data from it, but legit users will never get any data from it either.

One time pads do have the luxury of being provably impossible to break if used correctly, however they are cumbersome to use.  If they were the "best" option, then none of the other systems we know of today would exist as they almost all came about after the idea of the one time pad (which is a truly ancient concept.)

Rather, the best option is the one which mitigates your risks to acceptable levels while also maintaining an acceptable level of usability.  In many cases, the best security may well be no security.  For example, I don't care if you know my cookie recipes, so putting any effort to protect them would reduce usability unnecessarily.  I do care if my cooking recipes get lost, so I may want to store multiple copies and back them up somewhere, but I wouldn't access control them as it would be a waste of my time.

The same thought process is no less true for high security situations than for my cooking recipes.  It comes down to analyzing the risk as they apply to me (Oreo may care more about protecting their recipe) and then deciding what is my best option.  It is different for everyone and every situation and there is no universal answer.

Comment: +1 for "legit users will never get any data from it either"  And the lava, of course.

Comment: @Hopelessn00b - Ok, re-reading your comment from earlier, I think I get what you are saying about OTP not maintaining perfect information security (sorry, it is 2am here).  It does leak that you may have sent a message (but you may not have).  But that in no way aids in breaking the cryptography itself.  My statement is very clearly about being "impossible to break", not "impossible to make any observation about your action".  There is no information leaked which is useful in breaking the cryptographic protection of the message.

Comment: Oh, yes, there you go... that's what I was trying to get at. Not having perfect information security means that even the protection of perfect crypto won't perfectly protect your information, so even without breaking the crypto, some information can be gleaned. For some reason, I inferred an implication in your post that wasn't there about a properly implemented OTP equating to perfect information security.

Comment: That leakage that you may have sent a message, is part of the reason some people advocate using crypto all the time.  If you only use it for stuff that you really want to hide, then Eve can safely assume that she's just found something more interesting than your cookie recipe.

Comment: @chao it is worth pointing out that using crypto all the time doesn't hide that you sent a message, it just hides if it is interesting. Also, otp isn't limited to the Internet so it could be used through covert channels that are harder to track to you.

Answer (score 29):

No.   Not only does a one time pad suffer from secure key distribution problems Mike and gowenfawr mentioned in their answers but:

**Even if** if you did have a mechanism to securely distribute keys, the one time pad (by itself) has no mechanism for ensuring integrity.  The ciphertext is what we call "malleable" meaning  that it can be manipulated by an attacker to modify the plaintext message in predictable, undetectable ways.

**So**, even though the one-time-pad offers information theoretic perfect secrecy, it is not, by itself a secure cipher, and in the real world, easy to use authenticated ciphers with reasonably sized keys such as AES-CTR-HMAC or AES-GCM are clearly better.

Comment: True, OTP is meant to provide guaranteed secrecy, not guaranteed integrity. I don't think the attacker can modify the plaintext in a predictable way though unless the attacker knows (the corresponding part of) the plaintext message.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yes, and in the real world in which we live, and in which our ciphers must work, attackers frequently do.

Comment: If you encrypt and send a hash of the message along with the message, then malleability becomes very difficult (although I don't know *how* difficult).

Comment: This answer fails to mention that there are information-theoretically secure integrity schemes, e.g. Wegman-Carter, and at least in principle you could bundle it with the OTP in a sort of information-theoretic cryptosystem - it's good to mention that integrity/authentication is essential, but then quickly taking a shortcut to "easy to use authenticated ciphers" sounds very much like avoiding the question in the context of "why isn't one-time-pad encryption [read: information-theoretic security] the best"; OP is really asking about unconditionally secure cryptosystems, not OTP specifically.

Comment: @immibis If you send a *hash*, the difference is immaterial.  If you send a *MAC* then it becomes difficult, but unless you use a MAC algorithm that also provides information theoretic perfect secrecy, you've weakened your scheme, and the benefits of the one time pad no longer apply.  And you still have the problems of key distribution to deal with.

Comment: @Xander surely you only need a hash? The fact that someone correctly encrypted the hash with the OTP would seem to imply that either the hash algorithm is vulnerable, or they have the OTP.

Comment: @immibis No, that is still completely vulnerable to known plaintext attacks, thus not semantically secure.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, there are information theoretic secure integrity schemes, but that doesn't change the fact that a encryption system based on the one time pad is not in fact best.  I disagree that this isn't the question, as I've seen the same question in various forms a hundred times, but I'm open to being convinced that I'm wrong.

Comment: @Xander how is it vulnerable to known-plaintext attacks?

Comment: @Xander My point was that the OP is only talking about the one-time-pad because that's what he knows, and isn't aware either that authentication is important or that unconditionally secure MAC's exist (or both). If he were, he would not have excluded it from his question, since encryption without authentication is useless as you have explained in your answer, therefore adding a note that the authentication problem is not a fundamental problem with unconditionally secure schemes seems in order, as opposed to simply dismissing the option (irrespective of how viable such schemes are in practice).

Comment: @immibis It should be obvious.

Comment: @Thomas I'll agree that your argument is accurate, but the point of my answer was along the lines of gowenfar's critique of the transport mechanism, and that is this:  If you're trying to create an encryption system based on the one time pad, you're missing important things.

Comment: @Xander Fair enough

Comment: @Xander it's actually not obvious. Obviously, if the attacker can know the complete plaintext, then the encryption is broken already (how did they get the plaintext?) and any attacks resulting from this are moot. If they have part of the plaintext, an OTP-encrypted hash doesn't obviously give them more information about the rest of the plaintext. If they have the plaintext for one message, that doesn't seem to help them decrypt another message (which has a different OTP).

Comment: @immibis The point of a crypto system is to protect against all efficient attackers, not just one kind of attacker. Even though an attacker under KPA knows  the PT, the system should still be able to protect against him. With a bare hash OTP can't, because the attacker can not only modify the CT in a way that will predictably modify the PT, but can recompute the hash as well. By the time the message reaches the recipient, it has not only been modified by the attacker, but the original hash has been replaced by a the attacker's hash of the post-modification PT (or CT) and is hopelessly broken.

Comment: @Xander why would you send the hash unencrypted ??? You compress the original message, hash it and then encrypt compressed original+hash with OTP. I want to see the attack which changes the random bitfield in a way that the subsequent decompression and hash-check works...

Comment: And authentication will not be any problem, if you have somehow magically solved the secure key-exchange. If I share my OTP in person with only one person, and I decrypt a message with this OTP and the decryption produces a valid message, this is just as secure as any certificate (which is indirect just a proof that someone holds a private key - with OTP the private key is the OTP, so encryption and authentication in one)

Comment: I think what Xander is trying to say, that if you know both the plaintext and the crypttext, then you can calculate the OTP from them, and easily do a MITM attack. The other end will have no way of knowing that the message was tampered with, as it will perfectly decrypt with the OTP code.

Comment: @Falco  I explained at a high level a few comments earlier.  If it's still unclear to you and you need more detail, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @SztupY But how can he possibly know the plaintext, if part of it is completely random generated on creation of the message? No one can know this part. Since the Hash is derived from this, you also cannot know the hash. So the receiver can easily identify tampering by checking the hash-code, which the attacker cannot reproduce without knowing the random part of the message! - If the attacker would indeed infiltrate the senders computer and read the complete message including random chars prior to sending he could indeed forge it, but then he can probably just read a private key as well

Comment: @Falco You don't have to figure out how he knows the plaintext.  It is stipulated that for this attack, he knows the plaintext.  This is a part of standard crypto system design, and a strong system must be able to cope with this attack.

Comment: @Xander you are ignoring the fact that a secure hash encrypted with a secret key (OTP) is exactly the same as a MAC... Saying a MAC is more secure than an individually encrypted secure hash is somehow beside the point. Furthermore a KPA usually doesn't include the secret key and a random number of bytes appended as salt are not part of KPA, so the hash cannot be predicted and thus not forged

Comment: KPA is usually a scenario where the attacker can make an educated guess about what you want to send, but the plaintext only includes the actual plaintext, not the SALT and not the HASH and not the private key... and without these 3 any attack is futile and OTP is secure

Comment: @Falco Encrypting a simple hash with an OTP is not secure against a computationally unbounded attacker since the attacker can search for collisions offline. WC style MACs on the other hand are based on universal hashing, where you use one key to select a hash from a family of hashes, preventing collision search and then encrypting its output to prevent the attacker from learning anything about the first key.

Comment: If the hash is encrypted with an OTP, even if you could find any collision in seconds, how would you know you found one, if the hash itself is OTP encrypted? as long as you cannot decrypt the hash, you cannot look for collisions. And you cannot create the same hash, without knowing the SALT. You can't even search for patterns, since each bit is randomly encoded...

Comment: Imagine the following scenario: My Hash Function is a simple parity-bit, and I add one random bit to the plain-text before calculating the parity bit. - even if you know the plaintext and get my encrypted message, there is no way you can get a higher chance than 50% to guess the parity bit right because both bits (random and parity) are each xor-ed with a random Bit from the OTP... And this is even with a completely transparent reversal hash-function...

Comment: @Xander I understand how the attack you've detailed would work (and was tempted to explain it in a comment), but the comments suggest that it's not obvious to everyone. Perhaps it would be good to give an Alice-Bob-Mallory worked example?

Comment: @Falco In that situation, I compute a second message with the same parity (and same length) as the original, replace the original with it, and don't change hash or random bit. Alternatively, I compute a second message with opposite parity and flip the random bit. I have the ciphertext; I can either keep the random bit the same or flip it without having the slightest idea what it is, by keeping or flipping the corresponding ciphertext bit.

Comment: @cpast exactly! Because the parity function p(a||b) is the same as p(a)+p(b) so you can easily replace a with a colliding text. But this doesn't hold true for all hash functions! And even then the only thing you gain is a single collision, which will most likely not produce a usable text

Comment: @Falco A single collision is all you need to have violated the security properties demanded of message authentication (i.e. existential unforgeabilitiy under chosen-plaintext attack). It doesn't matter if it's "usable;" *any* forgery with probability more than 2^-(taglength) means you have a break. All hash functions have collisions; there is a very specific construct that can be used to provide perfect security, but no common hashing algorithms qualify.

Comment: If "the plaintext" includes any cryptographically secure hashes and salts, then clearly the message can be tampered with by an adversary who *somehow* knows the plaintext. I don't see how that's a plausible or practical concern.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to compare a **Cryptographic Primitive** and compare it to **Cryptographic system**. This is really comparing apples and oranges.

**Cryptographic Primitives** are put together to create a **Cryptographic system**, and you can only evaluate the security of a system once you understand the Use Cases and environment that the system operates in, including attackers, users, protocols on the wire, storage mechanisms, avenues of compromise, availability requirements, number of users, nodes, networks between, dependent services etc.

**So to your Question:**

So outside the context of the One Time Pad primitive, the system should probably introduce other techniques/primitives to support the following requirements.

- Integrity of Message (Checksums, Signing)
- Ensure synchronisation to avoid DOS. (An Attacker might introduce a bogus message to de-synchronises the communication between the parties).
- Stop Man in the Middle from Changing a single bit in transit (could change the meaning of a partially known plaintext by flipping one bit. i.e. "LaunchMissiles=0" versus "LaunchMissiles=1"
- Stop replay attacks ("Attack at Dawn" replayed three days later)

And Other Optional Requirements

- Sender Verification (Signing)
- Receiver Verification (Certificates)

So you could only attempt to evaluate the security of a Crypto-System once it is reasonably articulated.

Comment: Wouldn't "stop replay attacks" follow naturally from "never reuse key material" which is an absolute requirement for the OTP to be secure in the first place? Any message that uses overlapping key material should be thrown out as bogus without even being looked at any further than that.

Comment: Replay attacks can reuse previously valid messages, like the "Attack at Dawn" message that the evil villain resends to the recipient three days later. The message has metadata to ensure that the correct part of the OTP is used for decryption.

Comment: Exactly. The message metadata includes some sort of pointer into the key material (a starting location in the pad, if you will) and the message length. If that combination indicates an overlap with key material known to the recipient to have been used previously, the message should be discarded; it's either a replay, or *someone* doesn't know how to use an OTP securely.

Comment: Hi @MichaelKjörling all of the techniques you mention are *outside* the scope of the *One Time Pad* primitive. Note that you introduce another vulnerability above when you consider an attacker conducting a denial of service attack on the communication by forcing the one time pad to be marked as "used".

Answer (score 5):

The problem with a one-time pad is distributing it to both parties. You can't just put it on a server for them both to download, because if you had a secure channel to do that then the two parties could just use that secure channel to communicate anyway. You pretty much have to get both parties physically together, which is obviously very limiting.

Comment: Key distribution is a problem in some cases, but not all; it's not uncommon for two parties to have a secure communications channel before acquiring some information they'll want to transmit, but for the channel to be unavailable by the time they have the information to be transmitted.  OTP could be useful in such cases if other ciphers weren't essentially as good, and if the channel that would be available would be susceptible *only* to passive listening attacks.  I think a much more important aspect of OTP is the one mentioned by Xander.

Comment: @supercat OTP has, in fact, historically been used in exactly that kind of situation -- you can send a new tape via diplomatic courier on weekly flights to Moscow, and then not worry about key distribution when you're almost ready to launch nukes. Tampering is really not practical in that kind of situation (you need to know the contents of the message to effectively tamper with it), so it worked well enough in the Cold War.

Comment: @cpast: In some situations adversaries would have no knowledge of messages.  In others, however, adversaries might be able to guess.  For example, I read that in WWII there was a German desert base that allies were supposed to stay far away from because its predictable weather reports formed a useful crib.  If they'd been using OTP, someone who could intercept the transmission could have substituted any other desired message instead.

Answer (score 5):

An enduring problem with all encryption is **trust**.  You have to trust that the person you are sending a message to is on your side and won't deliver the message or key to someone who shouldn't have it.  You have to trust that the people who invented the encryption scheme you are using didn't include a backdoor or a flaw on accident.  With OTP, you have the problem of trust with the recipient, but if you cannot give the key to the recipient yourself physically, you now have to put trust in a **3rd party** entity that can deliver the key to the recipient.  This problem still exists today with modern encryption as well as authentication.

If I was a potential user, I would never put my trust in 3rd party that would generate a key and transmit it over a network connection.  There is also no way for a user to ensure that you are generating truly random keys or if you have been compromised.  It is definitely not proper use of OTP, as encryption is only as strong as its worst weakness.  If you are sending the key over the internet, you've lost any benefit that real OTP can provide and you might as well go with AES-256.

I think it is safe to say that OTP is technically the best transport encryption, the word "best" referring to security.  This does not mean that it's "best" for most use cases, and OTP has some serious negatives.  The key must be stored somewhere, and this means the key can fall in to the wrong hands.  Modern block ciphers usually have shorter keys that a human being can memorize, thus making it much harder for a 3rd party to extract them.  It's also really hard to poorly implement something like AES given the right software.

What you can count on more than the security of OTP is the laziness of human beings; we are naturally driven towards doing what is easiest, and this has historically led to people making some really bone-headed decisions that cost them the security of their communication channel.  Sometimes lazy humans decide to re-use keys once their key or code book has run out and they don't have the means to generate & transport a new one.  The result of this can be much worse than ceasing communication entirely.

Define best, and the answer may be yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the secure key exchange! If you can somehow connect to an always online server and can communicate with this server 100% secure - why don't you just relay your message over that server?

A perfectly valid scenario is the following: You meet someone in Person and exchange OTPs with him. After that you can communicate safely with him as long as the OTPs last. To ensure integrity of the messages and you will add N random bytes to your plaintext and then hash everything before encrypting with the OTP (I would usually also compress plaintext before encryption to ensure smaller size and higher information density). This will ensure authentication and encryption at once. Because authentication is in essence just verifying the other party knows some secret, which only he can know. But with symmetric secret keys the key is already a secret which only the two of you know, so if a message successfully decrypts with the shared secret key and is still intact (decompress + check hash) than integrity and authentication have been verified.

But if you want to use OTP against brute Force approaches, you can just as well use a big enough symmetrical encryption (like AES) which is also pretty infeasible to break. The interesting part of crypto is key-exchange. How can I do this whole encryption/authentication without meeting with everyone in person I want to communicate with securely? This is why asymmetrical encryption exists.

**So OTP solves a problem pretty good which is already solved good enough (symmetrical encryption) but doesn't solve the real problems at all, which are the reason for asymmetrical encryption!**

Comment: I doubt that "compression + hash" is really a way to provide integrity comparable to the security of the OTP. I'm not sure what the use of the compression step is supposed to be, and the hash alone doesn't provide protection against a known-plaintext MiTM attack. You should at least use a MAC (with additional key input), and I think there are MAC algorithms which have a similar theoretical protection level as OTP ... I would have to look that up, though.

Comment: Compression will save you bytes of your OTP and it will raise information-density making guessed-plaintext attacks harder. Furthermore a perfect encrypted hash is a really good way to protect against most attacks. But against known plaintext you would need an additional random component. Simply add N Random bytes to the plaintext before hashing where N is the hash-length. This will even make known plaintext attacks infeasible

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Can you explain to me the difference between a MAC (a secure hash algorithm encrypted with an individual key) and an OTP-encrypted hash (a secure hash algorithm with its own part of the OTP = individual key) ?

Comment: @Falco If the attacker knows the plaintext, then they know the hash of the plaintext and can replace both plaintext and hash with their own plaintext and hash. A MAC is _not_ "a hash encrypted with an individual key;" not all MACs even use hashes, and HMAC (which does) is H(k||H(k||M)), not E_k(H(M)), and encrypting a hash with a malleable encryption system *can't* produce a MAC. MACs have to be existentially unforgeable under known plaintext attacks -- if an attacker can get you to MAC as much as he wants, he can't feasibly fake *any* message-MAC pair that you didn't MAC for him.

Comment: @cpast ok - I want to see this You know the plaintext and will somehow magically guess my SALT you need to create the hash code ??? Remember you don't have the original hash, you don't have the original SALT and since SALT is as big as hash, you are just as good as completely guessing the hash... And just by using the hash-function two times doesn't change the fact that you have a function with two inputs: secret key and Plaintext. If the attacker knows both he can reproduce, if not then not. The same as encrypted Hash with unknown SALT

Comment: @Falco Where'd we get a salted hash? Salts are used in password hashes, not elsewhere, and are not secret. If you mean "I have a secret thing that I add to the message before hashing it," then you're not doing "hash and encrypt the hash". Incidentally, the point of HMAC is to work around certain issues with Merkle-Damgard hashes that makes H(k||plaintext) utterly unsuited for a MAC; that's why it hashes twice (with SHA-3, you can do H(k||plaintext), but that's not "do a hash and encrypt it," that's "have a secret key and use it in the hash itself" -- again, hashes don't generically have salts)

Comment: @cpast So I wrote in my answer "add N random byte before hashing" this is usually called salt. I add something extra to the plaintext so the hash is not easily predictable and not the same for a message with the same plaintext. Since I encrypt the Hash afterwards with the OTP I have effectively E(M||k||H(M||k)) So the Hash is Encrypted, which with an unpredictable OTP provides perfect security, superior to common MAC algorithms.

Comment: @Falco Using a secure hash function in that way is not sufficient for a perfectly secure MAC. For instance, the very common Merkle-Damgard family of hashes can't possibly provide perfect security with your construction: if I find a collision in the hash where the messages M and N are the same length (which I can do, because I have infinite computing power in perfect security analysis), and get M to be encrypted and MACed by you, I can swap out N for M and get a new valid message. Perfectly secure MACs exist. Your algorithm is not among them, with what you've said so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21091/discussion-between-falco-and-cpast).